# Is there a way to set a maximum size for a list?

Tags: java

I am looking for some help with the below problem. This is not my original code and I am quite new to Java, so I may be missing something obvious.

The code spawns some effects in a game I have, however there does not seem to be any upper limit on how many effects are spawned. Is there any way I can restrict the upper value of effects to some integer value? Say 20? Or can I make this value a random integer from say 20 to 30?

I have been trying to restrict the upper size of the list size but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions appreciated.

I have also tried adjusting the value `for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)` to something like `for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)`, but this seems to have no effect either and the effects spawn as before.

I have also tried removing `int i = list.size();` and  `Actor actor = (Actor)list.get(j);` so that the code just relies on the `for` loop, but the code will not compile: it seems to require the code `Actor actor = (Actor)list.get(j);`. I get a **`cannot resolve symbol`** error for the following:

```
symbol  : class pos  
location: package actor
            if(!flag && actor.pos.getAbsPoint().distance(point3d) < 10000D && (actor instanceof TypeBomber) && actor.getArmy() != myArmy)

symbol  : variable actor  
location: class com.maddox.il2.objects.vehicles.stationary.CandC$FireUnit
            if(!flag && actor.pos.getAbsPoint().distance(point3d) < 10000D && (actor instanceof TypeBomber) && actor.getArmy() != myArmy)

symbol  : variable actor  
location: class com.maddox.il2.objects.vehicles.stationary.CandC$FireUnit
            if(!flag && actor.pos.getAbsPoint().distance(point3d) < 10000D && (actor instanceof TypeBomber) && actor.getArmy() != myArmy)



public boolean danger()
{
    boolean flag = false;
    Point3d point3d = new Point3d();
    pos.getAbs(point3d);
    List list = Engine.targets();
    World.MaxVisualDistance = 50000F;
    int i = list.size();
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        Actor actor = (Actor)list.get(j);
        if(!flag && actor.pos.getAbsPoint().distance(point3d) < 10000D && (actor instanceof TypeBomber) && actor.getArmy() != myArmy)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int k = random.nextInt(500);
            int l = k - 250;
            k = random.nextInt(500);
            int i1 = k - 250;
            Eff3DActor.New(this, null, new Loc(l, i1, 0.0D, 0.0F, 90F, 0.0F), 1.0F, "Effects/Smokes/CityFire.eff", 600F);
            flag = true;
            int j1 = random.nextInt(10);
            wait = (float)(1.0D + (double)j1 * 0.10000000000000001D);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help. Like I said, I'm sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Why not just have a `maxActors` set to an arbitrary number and as you spawn, increment a local `counter`. Once `counter == maxActors`, break out of loop.

Comment: Why does "for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)" seems to have no effect? You are restricting the loop count to 20 instead of the list's size (hopefully the list contains at least 20 items). This seems to be correct.

Comment: don't know why "for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)" does not appear to work, it just runs as previously.

Comment: "Why not just have a maxActors set to an arbitrary number and as you spawn, increment a local counter. Once counter == maxActors, break out of loop."

Comment: again could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say for sure what all of that code is doing, however, it appears that your function actually returns flag past the point that you pasted? It also appears that the size of the list of Actors is the upper bound of how many smoke effects can be made (limited by how many pass the if statement).  That said I would try something like this (in order to preserve the rest of the function)

```
if(!flag && actor.pos.getAbsPoint().distance(point3d) < 10000D && (actor instanceof TypeBomber) && actor.getArmy() != myArmy)
        {
            if (renderedCount < 20)
                {
                Random random = new Random();
                int k = random.nextInt(500);
                int l = k - 250;
                k = random.nextInt(500);
                int i1 = k - 250;
                Eff3DActor.New(this, null, new Loc(l, i1, 0.0D, 0.0F, 90F, 0.0F), 1.0F, "Effects/Smokes/CityFire.eff", 600F);
                int j1 = random.nextInt(10);
                wait = (float)(1.0D + (double)j1 * 0.10000000000000001D);
                renderedCount += 1;
            }
            flag = true;
        }
```

Make sure you declare int renderedCount before the for loop.

Now this should limit the function to creating 20 smoke effects each time it is called.  Which brings us to the problems you are having where this kind of approach does not appear to work.  Since you mentioned this is a game, I would be willing to bet that this function is called many times a minute (more than likely once per 'game tick').  If that is the case, limiting the number of smoke effects created by the function will not appear to do much of anything in the game.  In order to limit the number completely you would have to do something a little more complex where you keep track of the number of smoke effects currently going globally.  Which would probably involve keeping track of how much time has passed since the effect was started... (which it appears that wait might be the time the effect continues after it is started).

As for suggestions about how to keep track of things globally I might recommend a singleton and some methods on the singleton canCreate() and didCreate(float timeValue) then replace renderedCount < 20 with canCreate() and replace renderedCount += 1 with didCreate(wait).

Anyway, I hope this helps you some.

p.s. the complexity that goes with limiting this is a prime example of why ModelViewController is so important when designing something like this...

**EDIT: rough singleton**

```
public class SmokeCountSingleton {
    private static SmokeCountSingleton instance = null;
    private List<Long> smokeList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    protected SmokeCountSingleton() {

    }
    public static SmokeCountSingleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new SmokeCountSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public boolean canCreate() {
        cleanList()
        return (smokeList.size() <= 20)
    }
    public void didCreate(float duration) {
        //duration appears to be in seconds but we want it in milliseconds
        smokeList.add(System.currentTimeMillis() + duration*1000) 
    }
    private void cleanList(){
        //remove items from list who have exceeded their duration
            // have a value less than System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

I do not have time to finish fleshing it out but hopefully that is enough to get you going.
The point of a singleton is that there is only ever one instance of it, it's kind of like having a database or some other external server that your program can use but without as much overhead.  This way you don't ever have to declare it either, so you don't have to worry about where you would need to declare it, but it still acts as if you have a global list. To access the singleton instance (and the methods) you would just do:

```
SmokeCountSingleton.getInstance().canCreate()
SmokeCountSingleton.getInstance().didCreate(someDurationValue)
```

Like I said earlier, my Java is a little rusty, and I just mocked this up in the edit window; so apologies if it doesn't work 'out of the box'.

Also, as a side note, you may very well have multiple threads running that call functions where this would get accessed.  So you may want to check out synchronized key word in Java...

Comment: Many thanks, i will give this a try an report back. Like you said though as this is a game i believe the function may be being called quite regular, i'll try what you suggested to see if it works.

Comment: @user2558274 you might also try commenting out the line Eff3DActor.new... to make sure that you are barking up the right tree

Comment: The line Eff3DActor actually controls the effect showing in game so i am not sure what good deleting it would do?

Comment: I am probably not going to get time to try this until later today, so i will report back then. Thinking aout it i believe the game makes regular checks to see if the player is within range and if so it then implements the code so i may have to consider the canCreate() and didCreate(wait) methods. Could you maybe expand on their use please and how i may use them in my situation? Regards Mike

Comment: @user2558274 well commenting out the Eff3DActor line temporarily would ensure that this is in fact the section of code that you want to limit... I've been programming in ruby mostly lately (so my java might be a little rusty) but I will give a shot at what the singleton might look like in a bit (and add it to my answer)

Comment: Just had time to try it out and very pleased to say your first post with the int renderedCount works perfectly. Can't thank you enough i am really chuffed.

Comment: Luckily i didn't have to get into the singleton method as it looks veery bewildering to me. Thanks again, really appreciate yours and everyone elses help on this

Comment: @user2558274 glad I could help, when you get a chance I'd appreciate my answer being marked as right... also the fact that my original suggestion worked means that most likely the wait value is being used somewhere to control how often that function is called...

Answer (score 0):

use **`list.size()`** directly, instead of passing it to i. It will return number of objects the list is holding. 
You can also use an `Iterator` or `ListIterator` to iterate through the list elements, as it will be easier, If you use these.
Example:-

```
Actor actor;   //It would be better if you create variable here and use the same variable for different objects.
Iterator iter = list.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    actor = (Actor)iter.next(); 
    ....//Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: could you give an example how to implement it for say 20 iterations please? I am a bit in the dark of how to do it.

Comment: @user2558274 It does not matter how many iterations are there, use the example i have given above, instead of the loop, just copy and paste your other code in it. It will work, give update on the status of your program.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a go and report back

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question regarding whether we can set a maximum for a list. Hope that will help you to get to know Java better :)

Generally, an implementation of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) does not have a maximum size, you can always add more element at the end of it.
In order to work around this would be to use a primitive array of Actor:

```
private static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ACTORS = 20
Actor[] actors = new Actor[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ACTORS];
```

That said, I would encourage you to use what the List interface has to offer to you, via its various implementations. Use, for example, an Arraylist and ovverride its add method:

```
public class ActorList extends ArrayList<Actor> {
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ACTORS = 20
    @Override
    public boolean add(Store s) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (this.size() <= MAX_NUMBER_OF_ACTORS){
            result = super.add(s);
        }else{
            // Notify number maximum of actors have been reached (logging, whatever processing you want here...)
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That would give you a nive control over the maximum size of your list of Actor instances.